# Python - take out the data inside cell of dataframe to another cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

This is the data in single cell of dataframe with 14 columns. Cell is the element of column. There are 45k+ this kind of cells, to do it manually is a hell.

[one cell data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZWrp.png)

I'd like to do with this cell 3 things:

1. move text part with address, state, zip - to another column;
2. delete the hooks () of cell;
3. separate for 2 columns longitude and latitude.

How it's possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple, working example with 2 data points:

```
text1 = """30881 EKLUTNA LAKE RD
CHUGIAK, AK 99567
(61.4478, -149.3136)"""

text2 = """30882 FAKE STR
CHUGIAK, AK 98817
(43.4478, -119.3136)"""

d = {'col1': [text1, text2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def fix(row):
  #We split the text by newline
  address, cp, latlong =  row.col1.split('\n')

  #We get the latitude and longitude by splitting by a comma
  latlong_vec = latlong[1:-1].split(',')

  #This part isn't really necessary but we create the variables for claity
  lat = float(latlong_vec[0])
  long = float(latlong_vec[1])

  return pd.Series([address + ". " + cp, lat, long])


df[['full address', 'lat', 'long']] = df.apply(fix, axis = 1)
```

Output of the 3 new columns:

```
df['full address']
0    30881 EKLUTNA LAKE RD. CHUGIAK, AK 99567
1           30882 FAKE STR. CHUGIAK, AK 98817

df['lat']

0    61.4478
1    43.4478
Name: lat, dtype: float64

df['long']

0   -149.3136
1   -119.3136
Name: long, dtype: float64
```

Name: full address, dtype: object

Comment: But one little problem 

latlong = latlong[1:-1].split(',')
NameError: name 'latlong' is not defined

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? I'm defining latlong in the previous line. Also, you wrote "latlong = latlong[1:-1].split(',')" when it is "latlong_vec = latlong[1:-1].split(','). That is, I'm creating a new variable latlong_vec.

Comment: Also, a remark: my code assumes that your column has no missing data (for example, all (lat, long) pairs are present). If this is not the case, you neeed to adapt the fix() function and add some try/catch clauses or some IFs to deal with border cases.

Comment: I'm sure that copied right, but also sure problem is in me. Will try to dig it in deeper. Cause you showed roadmap, I'm using my variables and somewhere there I'm wrong. Thank you so much Guillermo for detailed answer!