# Python, Pandas, dataframe - split and remove some parts of cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, data-science

Table with 10+ columns. Every cell in subject column has 3 elements: 1) address, 2) city-state-zip, 3) coordinates.

[column in csv with cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifYnV.png)

How to remove elements 1 & 2 and leave coordinates only without  hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the new columns as detailed in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61751967/745868), you can simply use the `drop` method from pandas to delete the ones you don't want to keep. For example, if you want to drop the **address** and the **col1** columns, you just write:

```
df.drop(['address', 'col1'], axis=1, inplace = True)
```

We use the **inplace** flag so that the columns are deleted from the dataframe. Otherwise, we would need to write something like:

```
df = df.drop(['address', 'col1'], axis=1)
```

because the command returns a new dataframe with the deleted columns. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)'s the documentation. Give it a look! It is super complete.